# Error with setting php file as img src

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm new to PHP and am trying to implement a captcha with PHP and jQuery using [this tutorial](http://www.jquery4u.com/validation/easy-jquery-php-captcha/). When the page loads, it shows a broken image instead of a captcha. When I click on the refresh image, I get this error in my console:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

I'm not really sure why I'm getting this error. Are there any server settings that I need to modify or am I simply missing some PHP?

form.html

```
<label class="" for="captcha">*Please enter the verication code shown below.</label>
<div id="captcha-wrap"><img src="/img/refresh.jpg" alt="refresh captcha" id="refresh-captcha" /> <img src="/php/newCaptcha.php" alt="" id="captcha" />
</div>
<input class="narrow text input" id="captcha" name="captcha" type="text" placeholder="Verification Code">
```

newCaptcha.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$string = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $string .= chr(rand(97, 122));
}

$_SESSION['captcha'] = $string; //store the captcha

$dir = '../fonts/';
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(165, 50); //custom image size
$font = "PlAGuEdEaTH.ttf"; // custom font style
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 113, 193, 217); // custom color
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); // custom background color
imagefilledrectangle($image,0,0,399,99,$white);
imagettftext ($image, 30, 0, 10, 40, $color, $dir.$font, $_SESSION['captcha']);

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
?>
```

main.js

```
WEBAPP = {

    settings: {},
    cache: {},

    init: function() {

        //DOM cache
        this.cache.$form = $('#captcha-form');
        this.cache.$refreshCaptcha = $('#refresh-captcha');
        this.cache.$captchaImg = $('img#captcha');
        this.cache.$captchaInput = $(':input[name="captcha"]');

        this.eventHandlers();
        this.setupValidation();

    },

    eventHandlers: function() {

        //generate new captcha
        WEBAPP.cache.$refreshCaptcha.on('click', function(e)
        {
            WEBAPP.cache.$captchaImg.attr("src","/php/newCaptcha.php?rnd=" + Math.random());
        });
    }

}

WEBAPP.init();

});
```

Comment: What does the output of the script look like if you view it directly?

Comment: Try moving your `header()` call before `session_start()`, which sends several headers of its own. Or remove `session_start()` completely.

Comment: Make sure that there is absolutely nothing (no spaces, tabs, newlines) after the closing `?>` in `newCaptcha.php`.... better yet, delete that closing `?>` completely

Comment: @GordonM, which script?

Comment: @Blazemonger, I'll try that out and let you know if it works

Comment: @MarkBaker I'll try it out and let you know if it works

Comment: @Blazemonger, that didn't work. Here's the error from the console:
"Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "php/newCaptcha.php?rnd=0.1490103267133236""

Comment: @MarkBaker, it didn't work. Same error as above

Comment: Try capitalising `Content-Type` correctly: `header('Content-Type: image/png');`

Comment: Possibly your server is set up to transmit *all* `.php` files as HTML?

Comment: @Blazemonger I'm not sure what that means. I have a php file handling form data and that works fine without the captcha